# A dictionary with a built-in factory?

Tags: c#

I have a solution that works, but for educational purposes I want to understand if there is a better/cleaner/right way to do it.

Problem: In my "client" app I have a dictionary `Dictionary<String, PremiseObject>` where the key (String) is a immutable URL to a resource (it's actually a REST URL).  PremiseObject is the base type of a whole set of derived classes; thus the Dictionary actually contains a family of classes all derived from PremiseObject.

A key requirement is I want to try to 'guarantee' that no PremiseObjects get created OUTSIDE of the dictionary.

Solution: I have the following function for getting a object out of the dictionary. It either accesses the existing instance, or if it does not exist creates it:

```
public PremiseObject GetOrCreateServerObject(string premiseObjectType, string location)
{
    PremiseObject po = null;
    if (!premiseObjects.TryGetValue(location, out po))
    {
        string classname;
        // Create an instance of the right PremiseObject derived class:
        po = // gobbly-gook that is not relevant to this question.
        premiseObjects.Add(location, po);
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Already exists: {0}", location);
    }
    return po;
}
```

Callers do this:

```
DoorSensor door = 
         (DoorSensor)server.GetOrCreateServerObject("DoorSensor", 
                                                    "http://xyz/FrontDoor");
```

Works great. But I think there's a pattern or design that would elegantly allow me to encapsulate the "single-instance of each object contained in the dictionary" more.

For example, callers could do this:

```
DoorSensor door = null;
if (!server.ServerObjects.TryGetValue("DoorSensor",
                                      "http://xyz/FrontDoor", 
                                      out door))
    Debug.WriteLine("Something went very wrong");
```

I'm not really what to call this pattern. My ServerObjects are "single-instanced" by location. And my GetOrCreateServerObject is like a factory that lazy creates.

But it's possible for instances to be created that don't get put into the dictionary, which could lead to problems.

Like I said, what I have works...  Cheers!

**UPDATE 1/26/2011 10:13PM -** 
I just realized a potential problem: On the server side the object represented by a `location/URL` can actually be multi-inherited. It is THEORETICALLY possible for an object to be both a `DoorSensor` and an `DigitalRelay`.

I currently don't care about any of those cases (e.g. for garage doors I simplified my example above; there really is no DoorSensor I exposed, just a GarageDoorOpener which includes BOTH properties for sensing (e.g. `Status`) and actuation (e.g. `Trigger`). But this puts a wrinkle in my whole scheme if I were to care. Since this project is just for me :-) I am going to declare I don't care and document it.

Comment: could there be more than one type of sensor at a location - for instance if the door was glass could you have a DoorSensor and a GlassSensor at the same location?

Comment: No, at this level we are discussing objects that are leafs. They have properties.

Comment: Neil, you were actually almost on to something..your question made me think and it is theoretically possible. See my update above.

Comment: @tig: multiple inheritance in C#? It's [not supported](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2004/03/07/why-doesn-t-c-support-multiple-inheritance.aspx), so you shouldn't care.

Comment: @tig - so If you get there - to where you need to support multiple sensor types, you will probably have to handle it by having you factory key you instance singletons by location and type - It would not be a big change to this code.

Comment: @vlad - I know C# doesn't support it.  But my back-end system does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok you can probably avoid a parameter and a cast (in the consumer code any way) with a generic method.

```
public abstract class PremiseObject
{
    protected PremiseObject()
    {

    }

    public string Location { get; set; }

    public static void GetSensor<T>(string location, out T sensor)
             where T : PremiseObject, new()
    {
        PremiseObject so;
        if(_locationSingltons.TryGetValue(location, out so))
        {
            sensor = (T) so; // this will throw and exception if the 
            // wrong type has been created. 
            return;
        }
        sensor = new T();
        sensor.Location = location;
        _locationSingltons.Add(location, sensor);
    }

    private static Dictionary<string, PremiseObject> _locationSingltons 
             = new Dictionary<string, PremiseObject>();
}
```

Then the calling code looks a bit nicer:

```
    DoorSensor frontDoor;
    PremiseObject.GetSensor("http://FrontDoor/etc", out frontDoor);
```

So I like that calling convention - if you want to stay away from throwing an exception you can change the return type to bool and indicate failure that way. Personally I wouls say that an exception is what you want.

You may prefer the call without the out parameter - but if you do that then you have to supply the type to the method call - anyway defining the factory method would look like this:

```
public static T GetSensor<T>(string location) where T : PremiseObject, new()
{
    PremiseObject so;
    if (_locationSingltons.TryGetValue(location, out so))
    {
        return (T)so; // this will throw and exception if the 
        // wrong type has been created. 

    }
    T result = new T();
    result.Location = location;
    _locationSingltons.Add(location, result);
    return result;
}
```

Then the calling code looks like this:

```
var frontDoor2 = PremiseObject.GetSensor<DoorSensor>("http://FrontDoor/etc");
```

I like both these approaches because nothing has to be repeated. The type of the `PremiseObject` only gets stated once - there is no need for a string defining the type.

Comment: My base PremiseObject can't be abstract. I have a bunch of standard properties all objects must inherit (e.g. Name, DisplayName, ID) and some other core functionality (I failed to mention that PremiseObject support IPropertyNotify via being derived from MvvmLight's ViewModelBase).  I don't think you meant to imply I had to use `abstract` for this though.

Comment: I think I now have my head around what you are suggesting by making `GetInstance` (see above; I think that's a better name than `GetSensor`) use generics. I don't understand how `GetInstance<T>(string loc, out T sensor) where T : PremiseObject, new()` would support `DoorSensor ds = PremiseObject.GetInstance(loc)`. Does `: PremiseObject, new()` mean "T can be any type derived from PremiseObject"?

Comment: It means that T **must** be derived from `PremiseObject` and **must** implement `new()`. You can have properties, methods and everything else on an abstract class - you just can't create an instance of an abstract class. That is to say actual instances must always be of a descendant type.

Answer (score 2):

I would propose the following simple idea:

1. `PremiseObject`'s constructor is declared internal.
2. A special factory object is responsible for creating (or returning an already created) instances. The dictionary is a part of the factory.
3. Clients are located in another assembly.

This way `PremiseObject`s can be created by clients only through the factory. This way you can guarantee that only single instance of object exists for each `location`.

---

A variant of the idea would be to declare the `PremiseObject`'s constructor private, and declare the factory a `friend`; but (unlike C++) C# doesn't have a `friend` notion.

Comment: I'd go with this.  Don't forget about thread safety - if two threads concurrently call into the factory with the same location, then only one thread should take on the responsibility of creating the PremiseObject.

Comment: @Daniel: Indeed. In a usual case a simple `lock` would do.

Comment: This is the general idea I think everyone posting is suggesting. What I see as the new question, though, is whether the factory should be part of `PremiseObject` or external to it.

Comment: @Vlad - maybe not so simple, but it depends on what the OP's needs are.  If you want to allow concurrent creation of PremisObjects by different threads, or not block threads from retrieving an existing PremisObject while others are being created, then the thread synchronisation gets trickier.

Comment: @tig: I think this choice is yours.  Personally I'd separate the concepts, but if you think they are coupled, then go nuts.

Comment: @Daniel Paull: The issue I have with coupling them, I think, is it makes the caller code less obvious. Objects magically having their lifetimes managed by some hidden internal system seems like magic that would be confusing. Given PremiseServer is effectively the holder of all of these I think I will stick with having the factory be on PremiseServer (e.g. `DoorSensor ds = server.GetOrCreateObject(...)`.

Comment: "Objects magically having their lifetimes managed by some hidden internal system" - you mean like garbage collection...

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be really, really sure that no instances of PremiseObject get created that aren't placed in the dictionary, you could make the constructors all private, and create a static constructor (for each subclass) that took as a parameter the Dictionary object you're referring to.  This static constructor would check the dictionary object to make sure that there wasn't an existing instance, and then return either the new or the existing instance as required.  So something like this:

```
public class PremiseObject
{
    public static Dictionary<string, PremiseObject> PremiseObjects { get; private set; }

    static PremiseObject()
    {
        PremiseObjects = new Dictionary<string, PremiseObject>();
    }
}

public class DerivedPremiseObject : PremiseObject
{
    private DerivedPremiseObject()
    {
    }

    public static DerivedPremiseObject GetDerivedPremiseObject(string location)
    {
        DerivedPremiseObject po = null;
        if (!PremiseObject.PremiseObjects.TryGetValue(location, out po))
        {
            po = new DerivedPremiseObject();
            PremiseObject.PremiseObjects.Add(location, po);
         }
        return po;
    }
}
```

And there are a variety of similar strategies you could use.  The key is to somehow make the constructor private and only allow access to the constructor through a static method that enforces the logic of the class construction.

Comment: Your code doesn't guarantee that the user will always supply the same dictionary. (If he doesn't, we fail to have singletons.) Perhaps the dictionary should be a static field of the `PremiseObject`?

Comment: Instead of passing the dict to the constructor, it could be a static, readonly member of PremiseObject?

Comment: Changing the name of `GetDerivedPremiseObject` above to `GetInstance` makes it really obvious this is a singleton factory: `DoorSensor ds = DoorSensor.GetInstance(location);`. I like it. It turns out the requirement I had early on that had me not use strong typing, but the `objectType` string no longer exists, so I can move to this model.  So far this is my favorite proposal.  I'm intrigued by the generic based solution Neil presents so I'm going to noodle on that next... Thanks.

Comment: Note update I added to my question above regarding multiply-inherited objects on the server side.

Comment: The down side to this approach is that you have to write this method for each `DerivedPremiseObject`. The generic solution avoids that. There is a way to implement this pattern generically though too. You introduce an intermediate abstract generic that has the relevant factory method in it. Let me know if you want details on it. The advantage being that you get to write the code just once rather than n times where n is the number of descendants.

Comment: I agree that it's a pain to write this method for every DerivedPremiseObject, and I like the generic solution.  There are two situations where this would be better than the generic, though: (1) If the client classes need to be in the same assembly, the internal access modifier doesn't protect against misuse; and (2) if the various derived premise objects need different parameters in their constructors, a generic solution wouldn't work.  I'm running into #2 right now on my current project: it would be nice to have generic signatures the way we have generic types.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could make PremiseObject a singleton, then you wouldn't have to worry about each object in the dictionary beign a single instance?

Comment: But I have 3 garage doors. Each has a property of "Opened" = True/False.  If DoorSensor : PremiseObject were a singleton they'd each always have the same value for "Opened".

Comment: Gotcha - I misunderstood the question.

Answer (score 0):

In the general case, setting access modifiers on your constructors should do the trick of not allowing anyone external to create the objects (barring reflection). However, these would need to be `internal`, so anything else in the assembly would be able to instantiate them.

I suspect many of your requirements may be met by using an off the shelf dependency injection container that supports singleton instances. It feels close, but maybe not quite the same.  (possibly [StrutureMap](http://structuremap.net/structuremap/), [Ninject](http://ninject.org/), [Castle Windsor](http://stw.castleproject.org/Windsor.MainPage.ashx), or [Unity](http://unity.codeplex.com/) in no particular order)